# I get a Server 2019 standard key from getsoftwarekey.com, it worked good, but Will it pass the microsoft audit?

Tags: windows-server-2019

I get a Server 2019 standard key from getsoftwarekey.com, it worked good, andI want to upgrade all my servers, is there any trouble in the future when Microsoft come to audit my server or license , because if i upgrade here , I can save the money for my company, everything is so hard during the Covid-19

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Some third party offering 70% discounts no questions asked is not legitimate. Windows and Office at retail do not go on sale that deeply, outside of some special program from Microsoft.

If you are facing hardships, tell that to sales. Develop a relationship with a reseller you trust, and have a licensing person explain to you how to achieve cost savings. Special pricing tends to be available to many organization types, non profits, government, education, start ups. This everybody has a different licensing scheme complication is why we cannot answer your specific situation on Server Fault.